# Set CSS rules depending the value of a table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

How can I apply my CSS rules on a `<td>` with a certain value inside?

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>John</td>
      <tr>
    </table>
```

For example, how can I set the `color:black` in the *td* with the value John? Is it possible only with CSS? How?

Comment: You can set a class for that

Comment: Nope, because the html is automatically generated and I can't add attribute. So, my only possible selector of the td is the value.

Comment: @PieroAlberto JavaScript would be an option here - are you open to JS solutions?

Comment: I prefer CSS, but, obiously, if is it necessary, js is more than ok! :)

Comment: No, you cannot do this via CSS (though there is a candidate for it [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/CR-css3-selectors-20011113/#content-selectors)). You will need to do this via javascript if you cannot add classes when the markup is generated.

Comment: @PieroAlberto You can't do this using `CSS` but if you want to do this using `jquey`, i post my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a JS solution, which loops through all instances of `td`'s and checks their contents. It appends a class to td's which have inner content of "John" in my example.

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  if(el[i].innerHTML == "John") {
    el[i].className += " " + "test";
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>John</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

EDIT - the above is a basic example of course - you can expand and tailor to your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question was not about how to set classes, but how to read/react to a certain elements content.

Theoretically this is not possible in the current CSS Spec. There are exceptions though:

1. :empty-pseudo-selector (only detects, whether the element is completly empty or not)

   ```
   td:empty {
     background-color: lightgreen;
   }
   ```

Detailed Example: http://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/pbJbOx

2. Write the Content in a data-attribute and afterward style according to it.

HTML

```
    <td data-val="Name"></td>
```

CSS

```
    td::after {
      content: attr(data-val);
    }
    [data-val="John"] {
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
```

Detailed Example: http://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/OXVXaO

This is an "hack" though and should be used with caution, because

- most Screenreaders won't see/read the value, as they ignore CSS-content
- you may no longer use a different content in the ::after pseudo element
- You cannot use this for displaying HTML-structures, only Text

PS: The mentioned ":contains" pseudo class was dropped and never made it into a Recommended CSS Spec. AFAIK, it's not supported in any major browser.

Answer (score 0):

1.HTML & CSS

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td class="red-flag">John</td>
  <tr>
</table>

<style>
 .red-flag{
   color:red;
 }
</style>
```

2.Option with jQuery:

```
 $("td:contains('John')").css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Nope, because the html is automatically generated and I can't add attribute. So, my only possible selector of the td is the value.

Comment: I've just edited my answer - you can do it with jQuery. In case you want to assign class to element based on its value you could do something like:  $("td:contains('John')").addClass('red-flag'); etc.